# Firestore, Python, update fields in documents retrieved by compound query

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I need to update a bunch of documents in a Firestore database.
I'm successfully retrieving them by using a query, but now I should update the same field in each of them and I'm having troubles with it.
This is what I tried:

```py
def main():
    db_credentials = "some_local_file.json"
    cred = credentials.Certificate(f"{db_credentials}")
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
    db = firestore.client()

    user_id = "user_ID_000"

    doc_ref_generator = db.collection(u'CollectionName').where(u'UID', u'==', user_id).where(u'Status', u'==', "Active").stream()

    for doc_ref in doc_ref_generator:
        doc_ref.update({u"Status": u"non_active"})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

and I'm getting the error:

```
File "/Users/user_name/projects/xxx/firestore_check.py", line 17, in main
    doc_ref.update({u"Status": u"non_active"})
AttributeError: 'DocumentSnapshot' object has no attribute 'update'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also have to specify the collection reference and get the document id when iterating the `stream()`. See sample code below:

```
# Collection Reference
col_ref = db.collection(u'CollectionName')
doc_ref_generator = col_ref.where(u'UID', u'==', user_id).where(u'Status', u'==', "Active").stream()

for doc_ref in doc_ref_generator:
  # Document Reference
  doc = col_ref.document(doc_ref.id)
  doc.update({u"Status": u"non-active"})
```

or you could use the `reference` property to get the document reference from the DocumentSnapshot:

```
for doc_ref in doc_ref_generator:
  # doc = col_ref.document(doc_ref.id)
  doc_ref.reference.update({u"Status": u"non-active"})
```

---

You can checkout this documentations for more information.

- [Update a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#update-data)
- [Reference](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/document.html#:%7E:text=Parameters-,reference,-(DocumentReference)%20%E2%80%93%20A)

Comment: Yes, I checked that page, but I didn't find it particularly clear. I mean, in the case reported there they're retrieving a single document, and I was assuming .stream() would return a list of objects analogous to what is returned by .document(). Thanks a lot for clarifying it!

Comment: Well, you still need to follow the same analogous from the documentation which indicates that you need a document reference to update to. I forgot to include that  DocumentSnapshot has a `reference` property that is better to use. I'll update my answer.